# How to force ActionScript 2 List component to redraw?

Tags: flash, actionscript, listbox, components, repaint

When the list item label is changed, the list doesn't redraw until I hover the mouse over changed item. I've tried `invalidate` & `redraw` but they didn't work:

```
//myList is an instance of mx.controls.List component
myList.getItemAt(0).label = 'New Label';
myList.invalidate();
myList.redraw(false);
```

How to force the list to redraw in this case?

Answer (score 1):

For anyone still looking for the answer. Here is a improper way to update the list, (I don't know of the proper way) But, using the sort method, and without putting any parameters for it sort, causes it to "Refresh (I guess)" or whatever it does.

USE:

```
myList.sortItems();
```

An Example:

```
myList.getItemAt(0).label = 'New Label';
myList.sortItems();
```

Comment: Hi, i also encounter this problem.
the sortItems didnt help, use the sortItemsBy
<br/>
myList.sortItemsBy("sortNum", "ASC");

take a look on the reference:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00002552.html

Answer (score -1):

use `refresh()` method:

```
list.refresh()
```